Visualization sum with specific dayOfWeek
I would like to create a Count visualization by selecting the weekdays for a given month. I’m able to create the visualization by using a sum on my TotalTTC field, but I want to sum only for the weekdays (Monday to Friday).
I’ve tried using the KQL syntax and/or Query DSL on @timestamp, but without success.
Do you have any suggestions?
I’m using ELK version 8.3.3.
